# How to execute some code whenever the user interacts with the map?

Tags: openlayers-3

I have an OpenLayers 3.9.0 map. I also have a pair of LonLat coordinates that I am tracking from an external source and updating onto the map. I am continuously re-centering the map on these coordinates:

```js
function gets_called_when_I_have_updated_coords() {
    map.getView.setCenter(coords);
}
```

What I want is to disable this auto-centering whenever the user interacts with the map. In other words, I want this:

```
var auto_center = true;

function gets_called_when_I_have_updated_coords() {
    if (auto_center) {
        map.getView.setCenter(coords);
    }
}

function user_started_interacting() {
    auto_center = false;
}
// But where should this function be attached to?
// where.on('what?', user_started_interacting);
```

I don't know how to detect a user interaction.

I expected that [the default interactions](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.html#.defaults) had some kind of event, so that when the user starts dragging/rotating/zooming the map, an event would be triggered and my code would run. I could not find such event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an workaround, I can attach an event to a change in the view:

```
map.getView().on('change:center', function(ev){…});
```

But I must take extra steps to distinguish from code-initiated changes from user-initiated ones. The complete code looks somewhat like this:

```
var auto_center = true;
var ignore_change_events = false;

function gets_called_when_I_have_updated_coords() {
    if (auto_center) {
        ignore_change_events = true;
        map.getView.setCenter(coords);
        ignore_change_events = false;
    }
}

map.getView().on('change:center', function() {
    if (ignore_change_events) {
        return;
    }
    auto_center = false;
});
```

Note that this approach breaks if [any animation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.animation.html) is used (and there is no callback or event for when an animation finishes).

Depending on your project, you may want to try either this solution or [Jonatas Walker's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32869471/).

Comment: So, how does this end up?

Comment: [In the end](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), this answer is [what I've implemented](https://github.com/mkoch227/ets2-mobile-route-advisor/commit/8547f718741ee6c9b903c8e14ffacaf5569f3818). For my specific case, I believe it was shorter and I could live without animations. But I recognize that for other cases your solution might be better; and someday in the future we may switch the code to your approach.

Answer (score 2):

Here, the user is dragging:

```
map.on('pointermove', function(evt){
    if(evt.dragging){
        //user interacting
        console.info('dragging');
    }
});
```

Here, the user is changing resolution:

```
map.getView().on('change:resolution', function(evt){
    console.info(evt);
});
```

**UPDATE**

Some options to detect keyboard interaction:

```
//unofficial && undocumented
map.on('key', function(evt){
    console.info(evt);
    console.info(evt.originalEvent.keyIdentifier);
});
//DOM listener
map.getTargetElement().addEventListener('keydown', function(evt){
    console.info(evt);
    console.info(evt.keyIdentifier);
});
```

[A fiddle to test](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/490xzbcr/).

Comment: This should work for both mouse-based and touch-based input. Mouse-wheel zooming is captured by 'change:resolution', but that event will also be fired for code-initiated `.setZoom()`. This will not work for keyboard-based input.

Comment: You said "I am continuously re-centering the map", so `setZoom()` is out of scope.

Comment: For keyboard, the answer code still needs to copy the logic that detects if the key input will be used for interacting with the map (for instance, pressing Tab wouldn't). For reference, the relevant code in OpenLayers is at https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/interaction/keyboardpaninteraction.js and https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/interaction/keyboardzoominteraction.js (There is no need to add it to the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

An other approach could be to listen to the `pointerdown` and `pointerup` events occurring on the map and while the down is in action, disable your auto-center feature.

```
map.on('pointerdown', function() {
  auto_center = false;
}, this);

map.on('pointerup', function() {
  auto_center = true;
}, this);
```

This approach may need more work, but it would be a start.  Thoughts ?

Comment: I couldn't find the [documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/index.html) for `pointerdown` and `pointerup` (but maybe it exists somewhere). I believe using such events will trigger even if the user clicks/taps on the map, without actually dragging it. I also believe it won't work for keyboard-initiated interactions. Finally, will them also work on touch-based devices? Gotta test this solution later.

Comment: The official API events are listed here: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.MapBrowserEvent.html.  You're right that `pointerdown` and `pointerup` are not so reliable.  You could use a combination of the official ones to do what you want.  See also: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/v3.9.0/src/ol/mapbrowserevent.js#L491

Comment: I've just tested this one. It works for touch-based devices. It does not work for mouse-wheel zooming. It does not work for keyboard-based input.