# How to differentiate changes in the movement of the map by the user and by a function, using OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a simple function where the user starts the GPS and the tracking position, where the map view follows him. I want to deactivate the follow function when the user pans the map, but keep the tracking position function activated, so the user can move the map and still view his position. I tried to use the [map events](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_MapEvent-MapEvent.html) (`moveend`, `movestart`, `change`), but they fire regardless of how the map moves. I also tried with the `click` event, but this event is not triggered when the map is panned, only when the click occurs quickly.

Is there a way to check this difference?

[OpenLayers track position example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geolocation.html) for reference

---

I found some related questions very similar to my problem: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36845572/7123439) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163355/7123439).

Quoting the second question:

```
map.on('moveend', function(event) {
  var mapView = map.getView(),
      moveInitiatedProgrammatically = mapView.get('moveInitiatedProgrammatically') || false;

  mapView.unset('moveInitiatedProgrammatically');

  // evaluate moveInitiatedProgrammatically's value and behave accordingly...
});

map.getView().set('moveInitiatedProgrammatically', true);
map.getView().setCenter(coord);
```

> It's not ideal for the following reasons:
>
> 1. Introduces additional state information in the map's view.
> 2. Carelessly replacing the map view will lose that state information.
> 3. Requires setting a property before changing the view state and may be too easily forgotten.
>
> However, it adresses my issue in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Jonatas Walker solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32869471/7123439), I believe I can differentiate one movement from another using the [`pointermove`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_MapBrowserEvent-MapBrowserEvent.html) event, which is not fired by the tracking function.

```js
map.on('pointermove', evt => {
    if (evt.dragging){
        console.info('dragging');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ol-ext](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext) `ol/control/GeolocationBar`. You can start a new track. When you move the map a `center` button let's you center back to the track.
See example online: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/mobile/map.control.geolocationbar.html